# How to get large data like some 300 documents from a collection using node.js, express.js and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I used `find` to get. This worked fine for few days but now it's not working properly. I'm using `mlab` to store data. I'm getting like below when requested in postman.

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:3060/subproduct.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
SSL connections are being blocked:
Fix this by importing SSL certificates in Chrome
Cookies not being sent:
Use the Postman Interceptor extension
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

When API is called on client side, it is showing error as

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

Where it went wrong?

Comment: Looks like your Node app is crashing. You should try to find out why (we can't tell you, because you're not posting any error logs or stack traces).

Comment: I have hosted my code in openshift, in that it is showing the log regarding ruby as mentioned in the earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242584/i-had-hosted-my-server-side-node-js-and-express-js-code-on-openshift-from/39250021#39250021)

Comment: What does Ruby have to do with Node?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the api from client side you are  doing an `XMLHttpRequest` to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request.Please  add the following middle ware for fixing this issue.

```
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```